# Multiple SSH Commands while in a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

In one section of a bash script, I need to ssh into a remote box, change to root, then deploy an rpm. My code is getting stuck after it changes to root and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ideally I would like it to ssh in, switch to root, deploy the rpm, then exit the ssh session.

```
user="user"
host="hostname"
echo "Enter password: "
read -s pw
ssh -t "$user"@"$host" "sudo su; $pw; rpm -Uvh rpmtodeploy.rpm;"
```

This is what I get currently:

> user@localhost:~$ bash rpm.sh
>
> Enter password:
>
> [root@hostname /home/user]#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you background a command, bash waits for it to exit before executing the next command. Since `su` is spawning an interactive shell, it will continue to run until you close it. You should use sudo directly:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh rpmtodeploy.rpm
```

If you have `sudo` access to `su` but not to `rpm`, use the `-c` option:

```
sudo su -c 'rpm -Uvh rpmtodeploy.rpm'
```

Comment: How would I pass my password through the first command? sudo rpm -Uvh rpmtodeploy.rpm

Comment: @Konnor You don't. Configure `sudo` to allow `NOPASSWD` for the `rpm` command. If you are unable to do that, you will have to use an `expect` script.

Comment: Ah ok, I was looking into that earlier. Thanks @jordanm